# Mail Storage Quota Checker in C#

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, ldap, exchange-server

We have a requirement to build a tool for users in an Intranet scenario. 
The tool should check how much percentage of the Mailbox Quota (set in Active Directory) is being used.
Currently, they can check their Folder size using Outlook 2003 but this does not show the Quota Limit set for them or the percentage being used.

This [blog](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2005/03/relating-mailbox-sizes-to-mailbox.html) has all the exact information I need including [vbscript samples](http://msgdev.mvps.org/exdevblog/mblimquerybyemail1.zip). 
If you have any similar C# code, please post it.
That will give me a good lead on writing a small system tray application which will poll the Active Directory and show the percentage in real time.

PS: I am not being lazy. Already started writing code for this. Just checking if any of you went through a similar exercise and have code to share.

Answer (score 2):

Querying ActiveDirectory is pretty simple.  You can find some good examples I've used before [here.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/activedirquery.aspx)